# onchange not working for select created using dd

Tags: jquery, msdropdown

I have created an select box using dd:

```
<select id="Size1"  class="mydds" style="width:180px;">
<option value="/p/1">1</option> 
<option value="/p/2">2</option>
<option value="/p/3">3</option>
</select>
```

Inside `(document).ready` I added the following line:

```
$(".mydds").msDropDown();
```

I tried to bind `onchange` using

```
$('.mydds').on('change',function() {
    alert("hiiiii");
});
```

But not able to bind the event can you help me on this?

Comment: Any JS errors on your browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var myddsAux = $(".mydds").msDropdown().data("dd");

  myddsAux.on('change', myddsFunction);

  var myddsFunction = function ( event ){
      alert("hiiiii");
  }
});
```

;)

PD: [Documentation msDropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/examples/help.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(".mydds").on('change', 'select', function() {
alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get multiple variables from msDropdown, depending what you need,

here is example to get the text

```
        $(".mydds").change(function() {
            var oDropdown = $(".mydds").msDropdown().data("dd");
            var text = oDropdown.get("selectedText");
            console.log(text);
        });
```

there are also other properties available like:

- selectedIndex - number
- selectedOptions - array
- value (select option value)

Answer (score 0):

Following is working for me

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $(".mydds").on('change', 'select', function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

});
```